# QNetworkAccesManager memory leak

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

Why this code, running repeatedly in a custom object moved to QThread instance, produces memory leak?

```
void QCustomHTTPManager::compare()
{
    // custom code to create request and  multiPart content
    QNetworkReply *reply = networkaccessmanager->post(request,&multiPart);
    connect(reply,&QNetworkReply::finished,eventloop,&QEventLoop::quit);
    eventloop->exec();
    emit compared();
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

memory leak is around 8 bytes per call

Platform: Ubuntu 20.04, x86_64 CPU, Qt 5.14.2

To check maybe some other parts of my program belongs to the leak i have remove post() and no memory leak has been detected:

```
void QCustomHTTPManager::compare()
{
     // custom code to create request and  multiPart content
    QTimer::singleShot(1,loop,&QEventLoop::quit);
    eventloop->exec();
    emit compared();
}
```

Comment: `memory leak is around 8 bytes per call` - how do you measure this? Also don't use a local blocking eventloop but proper signals and slots instead.

Comment: Memory leak measurements has been performed by means of htop and gnome-system-monitor. As long as my eventloop lives in separate thread it is pretty normal to use it as I have used.

Comment: You see 8 bytes of memory leak in a tool not designedfor such a task? Wow. Since your're using Qt 5.14 you should take a look at this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88560) which was fixed within this [report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88063)

Comment: Ok, @chleric, if you prefer, I have found constant memory consumption grow. As you can see in my snippet, I have not save any data after HTTP request. But application occupies more and more memory. For the instance app starts with Memory: 14 MB and after 10 minutes Memory: 334 MB and so on

Comment: If it's not the bug explained in my two links I suggest to use a tool which is designed to find memory leaks like valgrind or address sanitizer. Also please provide a minimal,  compilable example to reproduce your leak.

Comment: I have performed experiments with other versions of Qt:  5.9.7 - no leak; 5.14.2 - leak; 6.4.1 - no leak

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of Qt build 5.14.2. No memory leaks for the requested code above have been reproduced with Qt 5.9.7 and 6.4.1